# Slice html template into Magento theme

Tags: html, css, magento, templates

I have HTML Template. I want to integrate that template to Magento theme. I have searched over google as well as here(Stack-Over-Flow). But not getting proper documentation for that. Any help will appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question you are asking is too broad.You have to be specific because different pages are rendered from different template file .So be specific in which page you want your template to be implemented.

Comment: I want to integrate whole html template as Magento theme. Which includes home-page, product-page and everything that HTML-TEMPLATE have. @aton1004

Comment: You are asking whole bunch of magento in one question and asking for a single documentation.You will not get any. You have to full understand magento to do so.

Comment: I am not asking for single doc. I`m not getting a GOOD or a SINGLE document over integrating html template to MAGENTO theme. Even not getting document over WHERE to START from. By the way, I have found the MagentoDesignGuide.pdf which is good to START. @aton1004

Comment: Learning about Zend Framework and Model2 is a good place to start, then you'll be ready to understand how the view works. You'll be very frustrated when you try to access things the view shouldn't have access to ;)

Comment: I think you did not get the question. @NickM

Comment: @MaulikM.Dodia as a veteran Magento EE/CE developer, I did get the question, and pointed out that to understand the theming of a Model2 framework, you need to understand first how the view works. Otherwise you are going to make mistakes that will cost both you and clients large sums of money in the future. Learn how Model2 works, then read the Magento PDF you have, and it will be much clearer. For instance, hardly ANY logic should ever be done in the phtml files. Like zilch, zero, none. This is contrary to most entry-level PHP devs experience prior to Magento or other frameworks.

Comment: So, First of all I have to learn Model2 framework. Than I can start learning Magento. Can you provide some good documentation over Model2 framework. @NickM

Answer (score 1):

Ok You want to integrate the static HTML template to the magento theme. So let's divide things you need to learn and how to learn efficiently.

Magento can be basically divided into three parts:

1. Admin panel: As you know magento is a CMS so most of the basic things could be managed from backend.For example static pages and Home pages could be managed from "CMS Pages" from admin panel.
2. Next is theming: You have mentioned about the MagentoDesignGuide.pdf this could be the start. I recommend you to have a look for the youtube channel of leveluptuts for the theming(layouts).This is very important for structuring your pages and site.You can follow other also but i prefer that because i also learnt from it and was very helpful.
3. Another is the module development portion.In some cases you need to develop custom modules .So this would be the last part.There are great tutorial provided by **Inchoo** and **Smashing Magzine** for developing custom module.

All of these things are required to fully develop a magento site. If you understand this than you will do great in magento.

Hope this answer provides you with the idea of how to proceed further and also helps you to divide the way of learning Magento.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Thanks for understanding my question. I have understand very well as what you have told.I will take a look at your reference links. Thanks for helping me. If you dont mind, Can I ask you a question? @atom1004

Comment: Have you removed the previous answer to this question? @atom1004

Comment: Which previous answer there is only one answer to this question in which we are commenting right now.There are no any other answer.

Comment: There was another answer which have just a link. Anyway thanks for help. @atom1004